# stable octave on MATE

Tags: ubuntu-mate, octave

I installed [Octave](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) on my RPi400 running 32-bit Ubuntu [MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) for Raspberry Pi with the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

It installed fine the first time but flaked out a little when i tried to install [MATPOWER](https://matpower.org/).  So, i uninstalled it with,

```
sudo apt-get remove octave
sudo apt-get purge octave
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Next, i reinstalled Octave.  I get no error messages that i can see.  But, when i run Octave it shows up for a second or two and then vanishes.  I'm wondering if i haven't really gotten rid of the first install that may have been corrupted with a bad attempt at installing MATPOWER.

`cat /etc/os-release` gives,

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=groovy
UBUNTU_CODENAME=groovy
```

How can i install an older, stable version of Octave?  What is the latest stable version to run on Ubuntu MATE?

**UPDATE**:  Added info below from `octave-cli`

```
rr@rpi400:~$ octave-cli
GNU Octave, version 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf".

Additional information about Octave is available at https://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit https://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read https://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

octave:1>
```

I also ran `test mean` and it passed with 20 out of  20.  I then ran `__run_test_suite__` and everything came back **PASS** with the exception of just a few that were "reported bug" or "missing feature".

Comment: The version of octave in Ubuntu 20.10 is 5.2. Is the version of MATPOWER you installed compatible with that?

Comment: That I don’t know (nothing on MATPOWER page says).  But, now I can’t even get octave running by itself.

Comment: What happens when you enter the command `octave-cli` in a terminal? Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: The failure to load may be an issue with your personal octave configuration files ex. `~/.config/octave`

Comment: I reinstalled octave and ran `octave-cli` and added the result as an update above.  I also ran some tests and added that info too.  I'll look at what @steeldriver suggested next.

Comment: Ok, i went to `~/.config/octave` and deleted the qt-settings file.  The Octave gui starts fine now!  I'll test and see what MATPOWER install is doing to change this file - will post back what i find if anything.  Thanks @steeldriver and @archismanpanigrahi !!

Answer (score 2):

Simply deleting the `~/.config/octave/qt-settings` file solved the problem.  Starting the gui after deleting that file made it create a new one and it now works fine.

Ok, I compared the old qt-settings file (when octave gui would not run) with the new one that was created (I deleted the old qt-settings file and starting octave gui created a new one). The old file was 39kB and the new one is 22kB.  I'm not showing all the changes because it would be too big - but below are those in the general section.

[image]

I reinstalled MATPOWER and this time it runs fine.  I ran all the diagnostic testing and all is fine.  Something must have happened when i did the install the first time that corrupted that qt-settings file.  Anyway, simply deleting it is the fix.